# Rendering of bookdown book fails with pandoc error code 137

Tags: pandoc, bookdown

I am rendering a book with bookdown to PDF, that uses pandoc under the hood.

The rendering fails with:

"pandoc document conversion failed with error 137"

I cannot find out what the error stands for.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an "Out of memory" error. The only solutions I'm aware of are reducing document size or getting more RAM.